# Calculating TenkanSen an KijunSen (Conversion line and Base line) in Ichimoku indicator using JavaScrpit

Tags: javascript, math, indicator

We have set of data for each period (such as daily including today and days before) that consists of 4 data, open, lowest, highest and close.
TenkanSen is a number that is calculated by adding highest high between last 9 periods to their lower low divided by 2. and the number of periods to calculate for KijunSen is 26.

The information history is in the following format: [ih].[n].PriceMax for highest price and n is the number of days (before) so we know that [ih].[0].PriceMax is the highest from yesterday. Lowest uses [ih].[n].PriceMin and do the math yourself!

Now that the 9 periods high is between [ih].[0].PriceMax to [ih].[8].PriceMax for TenkanSen, and [ih].[0].PriceMax to [ih].[25].PriceMax for KijunSen, how can we calculate TenkanSen an KijunSen?

I used this

```
var TenkanSenMin = ([ih][0].PriceMin+ [ih][1].PriceMin+ [ih][2].PriceMin+ [ih][3].PriceMin+ [ih][4].PriceMin+ [ih][5].PriceMin+ [ih][6].PriceMin+ [ih][7].PriceMin+ [ih][8].PriceMin)/9


var TenkanSenMax = ([ih][0].PriceMax+ [ih][1].PriceMax+ [ih][2].PriceMax+ [ih][3].PriceMax+ [ih][4].PriceMax+ [ih][5].PriceMax+ [ih][6].PriceMax+ [ih][7].PriceMax+ [ih][8].PriceMax)/9

var TenkanSen = (TenkanSenMin + TenkanSenMax) / 2;

var KijunSenMin = ([ih][0].PriceMin+ [ih][1].PriceMin+ [ih][2].PriceMin+ [ih][3].PriceMin+ [ih][4].PriceMin+ [ih][5].PriceMin+ [ih][6].PriceMin+ [ih][7].PriceMin+ [ih][8].PriceMin+ [ih][9].PriceMin+ [ih][10].PriceMin+ [ih][11].PriceMin+ [ih][12].PriceMin+ [ih][13].PriceMin+ [ih][14].PriceMin+ [ih][15].PriceMin+ [ih][16].PriceMin+ [ih][17].PriceMin+ [ih][18].PriceMin+ [ih][19].PriceMin+ [ih][20].PriceMin+ [ih][21].PriceMin+ [ih][22].PriceMin+ [ih][23].PriceMin+ [ih][24].PriceMin+ [ih][25].PriceMin)/26


var KijunSenMax =([ih][0].PriceMax+ [ih][1].PriceMax+ [ih][2].PriceMax+ [ih][3].PriceMax+ [ih][4].PriceMax+ [ih][5].PriceMax+ [ih][6].PriceMax+ [ih][7].PriceMax+ [ih][8].PriceMax+ [ih][9].PriceMax+ [ih][10].PriceMax+ [ih][11].PriceMax+ [ih][12].PriceMax+ [ih][13].PriceMax+ [ih][14].PriceMax+ [ih][15].PriceMax+ [ih][16].PriceMax+ [ih][17].PriceMax+ ([ih][18].PriceMax)+ [ih][19].PriceMax+ [ih][20].PriceMax+ [ih][21].PriceMax+ [ih][22].PriceMax+ [ih][23].PriceMax+ [ih][24].PriceMax+ [ih][25].PriceMax)/26

var KijunSen = (KijunSenMin + KijunSenMax) / 2;
```

Comment: Dear @Daedalus this code is sent by mistake and is from another question. On the other hand I have made the code by finding the simple command of Math.max and the question is answered already. If I don't delete it it will rise a code war and I decide to let you manage this. So that's your decision what to do with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple math code:

```js
var TenkanSenMin = Math.min([ih][0].PriceMin, [ih][1].PriceMin, [ih][2].PriceMin, [ih][3].PriceMin, [ih][4].PriceMin, [ih][5].PriceMin, [ih][6].PriceMin, [ih][7].PriceMin, [ih][8].PriceMin)


var TenkanSenMax = Math.max([ih][0].PriceMax, [ih][1].PriceMax, [ih][2].PriceMax, [ih][3].PriceMax, [ih][4].PriceMax, [ih][5].PriceMax, [ih][6].PriceMax, [ih][7].PriceMax, [ih][8].PriceMax)

var TenkanSen = (TenkanSenMin + TenkanSenMax) / 2;

var KijunSenMin = Math.min([ih][0].PriceMin, [ih][1].PriceMin, [ih][2].PriceMin, [ih][3].PriceMin, [ih][4].PriceMin, [ih][5].PriceMin, [ih][6].PriceMin, [ih][7].PriceMin, [ih][8].PriceMin, [ih][9].PriceMin, [ih][10].PriceMin, [ih][11].PriceMin, [ih][12].PriceMin, [ih][13].PriceMin, [ih][14].PriceMin, [ih][15].PriceMin, [ih][16].PriceMin, [ih][17].PriceMin, [ih][18].PriceMin, [ih][19].PriceMin, [ih][20].PriceMin, [ih][21].PriceMin, [ih][22].PriceMin, [ih][23].PriceMin, [ih][24].PriceMin, [ih][25].PriceMin)


var KijunSenMax = Math.max([ih][0].PriceMax, [ih][1].PriceMax, [ih][2].PriceMax, [ih][3].PriceMax, [ih][4].PriceMax, [ih][5].PriceMax, [ih][6].PriceMax, [ih][7].PriceMax, [ih][8].PriceMax, [ih][9].PriceMax, [ih][10].PriceMax, [ih][11].PriceMax, [ih][12].PriceMax, [ih][13].PriceMax, [ih][14].PriceMax, [ih][15].PriceMax, [ih][16].PriceMax, [ih][17].PriceMax, ([ih][18].PriceMax), [ih][19].PriceMax, [ih][20].PriceMax, [ih][21].PriceMax, [ih][22].PriceMax, [ih][23].PriceMax, [ih][24].PriceMax, [ih][25].PriceMax)

var KijunSen = (KijunSenMin + KijunSenMax) / 2;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).